# What is the point of UNIX's rmdir?

Tags: unix, posix, rm

I'm new to UNIX (MAC OS X bourne shell POSIX), I understand `rmdir` will only remove an empty directory but under what circumstances would you actually want to use `rmdir <directory name>` and not just `rm -r <directory name>`?  Is there an intelligent use case I'm failing to appreciate and that knowing about would make my programming that little bit better if I did?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rmdir` is safer: it refuses to remove a directory if it contains any files. What if you are trying to remove the wrong directory, or the directory still contains (possibly hidden) files you need?

There are also [historical reasons](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue49/fischer.html): in the beginning the `rm` program didn't have a `-r` switch, so `rmdir` was needed to remove directories. Back then `rmdir` was a non-trivial program, but today it is just a wrapper for the `rmdir(const char*)` C function.

Answer (score 3):

I use `rmdir` when I'm removing a directory that I *expect* to be empty, so that it will fail if there are still files in it. Using `rm -rf` might blow away files that I want to keep, if I mistype something.